# How to replace part of the path?

Tags: c#, path

I'm making a batch processing application that should convert files from directory A and place them into directory B preserving the same path after the relative root directory. To do that I need some way to convert the input file path into output file path.

Example:

```
before: C:\MyProject\Files\Input_\file1.cs
after:  C:\MyProject\Files\Output\file1.cs
        ———————————————————       ————————
          ↑ ↓ these remain unchanged ↑ ↓
        ———————————————————       —————————————————————————
before: C:\MyProject\Files\Input_\folder\subfolder\file2.cs
after:  C:\MyProject\Files\Output\folder\subfolder\file2.cs
```

I hope it's clear what I'm after. Is there a standard method in `System.IO` namespace that can do this? If not, how do I implement it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**String.Replace("Input_","Output");**

Get the path and assign to a string variable and do a replace.

Comment: +1. If you know the exact segments and sure it does not ever happen in wrong place this approach works. Unfortunately even with `Path` class you will still need reasonable amount of raw string manipulations.

Comment: what if the input is `C:\MyProjects\file.cs\Whatever\file.cs`?

Comment: You can create a private method which will have string to replace as argument. And return the new string

Answer (score 0):

[Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class may help (at least in splitting file name from path and combining back), but you may need to do some string manipulations yourself too to replace particular component of the path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.Replace for path's strings.